# Python code returns "cannot import name 'keys' from 'selenium.webdriver.common.keys'"

Tags: python, voice-recognition, pyaudio, watson-assistant

I have this code and it's not working. How can I resolve it?

```
from selenium import webdriver  # to control browser operations
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import keys
from io import Bytesio
from io import Stringio


runfile('/Users/saksham/saksham py/voice.py', wdir='/Users/saksham/saksham py')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-f68c9e511ab8>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/saksham/saksham py/voice.py', wdir='/Users/saksham/saksham py')

  File "/Users/saksham/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Users/saksham/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/saksham/saksham py/voice.py", line 9, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import keys

ImportError: cannot import name 'keys' from 'selenium.webdriver.common.keys' (/Users/saksham/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/keys.py)
```

Comment: Is that an error, or a piece of code and an error smushed together?

Comment: @DeepSpace No they need to uppercase keys based on the [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import keys
```

With

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

[Based on the documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)

Comment: I think your directory is wrong too - can it really be saksham py?